# How can I logout and revoke all oauth tokens in laravel 8 api?

Tags: laravel, api, token, logout

The api I built with passport and laravel 8 does not logout by default.

I found a script, but it does not remove the entries in the oauth-access-tokens table

I added a function to the AuthController:

```
 
    public function logout(Request $request){
        $accessToken = auth()->user()->token();
        $token= $request->user()->tokens->find($accessToken);
        $token->revoke();
        return response(['message'=> 'Je bent uitgelogd'], 200);
    }
```

And added a path in api.php:

```
Route::post( 'logout', 'App\Http\Controllers\API\AuthController@logout')->middleware('auth:api');
```

When I try to logout with Postman, I get a success message, but the entry in the oauth-access-token table is not removed.

I intend to remove all tokens for the user, to log out from all devices

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I have created an article about the issue and wrote about solution - https://emciyevabdulla.medium.com/laravel-passport-logout-auth-user-from-all-devices-super-easy-way-d0638d8a6011

Answer (score 2):

Change the logout function to be like:

```
public function logout(Request $request){
    $user = Auth::user()->token();
    $user->revoke();
    return response(['message'=> 'Je bent uitgelogd'], 200);
}
```

This will log the user out from the current device where he requested to log out. If you want to log out from all the devices where he's logged in. Then do this instead:

```
use Laravel\Passport\RefreshToken;
use Laravel\Passport\Token;

public function logout(Request $request){
    $tokens =  $user->tokens->pluck('id');
    Token::whereIn('id', $tokens)->update(['revoked', true]);

    RefreshToken::whereIn('access_token_id', $tokens)->update(['revoked' => true]);

}
```

This will revoke all the access and refresh tokens issued to that user.

Comment: Thanks, Tried it. Does not work unfortunately. I do have a warning in VS CODE: "Undefined method 'token'.intelephense(1013)". I figured that was due to settings in vs code.    The first solution shows the successresponse, but entries in oauth-access-tokens remain. I cannot do the post twice, because then I am unauthorized. So it logs me out, but does not remove the entry from the table.. I guess.   2nd function returns : "message": "Call to a member function pluck() on null", in response.

Comment: Now I see that $request is never used in the functions you described... Should'nt AUTH extract a user from the token or something?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

I used the following code:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

and  the function:

```
public function logout(Request $request){
    Auth::user()->tokens->each(function($token, $key) {
        $token->delete();
    });
    return response(['message'=> 'Je bent uitgelogd'], 200);
   
}
```

So nothing is revoked, but all the tokens are just deleted..

Answer (score 0):

If your are using passport,
**Auth::user()->AauthAcessToken()->delete();**
will remove all the tokens of the user.

Answer (score 0):

In the AuthController i use this code

```
public function logout(Request $request) {
    
    $request->user()->token()->revoke();
    return response([
        "message" => 'Session finished',
    ],200);

    
}
```